# how to create a /dev/sdb device block in centos 7

Tags: linux, filesystems, centos7, partitioning

I'm installing a software which requires to write data on a disk (i.e.: `/dev/sdb`) persistently, unfortunately I only have /dev/sda which isn't suitable - I need a second disk to use.

I'm trying to write an empty image of the desired size and then assign it to loop device as in [this link](https://superuser.com/a/686160) but the solution does not cover how to persist data over reboots and I don't know if it's the best way to go.

edit:
the software I'm using is Ceph and during the creation of OSDs is required to specify a device block (not partition).

Comment: You could put the required commands to set up the loop mount into a script that is called on system startup or just before starting your "*a software*". Does your software really want to write to a raw disk, e.g. `/dev/sdb` instead of a partition, e.g. `/dev/sdb1`? Without more detailed information it is difficult to give specific advice. Why not simply add another disk, e.g. a USB pendrive?

Comment: the software I Ceph, I didn't say it to leave the question more general.
In the phase of OSDs creation (objects storage)I need to specify the block device and not the partition

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information, don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: In the script that runs the install, are you able to locate where it requires to use /dev/sdb ? If so, you could replace /dev/sdb with what you have which is /dev/sda and then re-run it again so that the scripts proceeds with the installation on a disk partition that actually exists. The alternative is to create /dev/sdb by resizing your / dev/sda using a tool like gparted.

Comment: In the link, the file virtual_hard_drive.bin will persist.  If you need it mounted at boot, you will need to script the losetup command to run at boot time.

Comment: @Joseph could you please suggest how to resize /dev/sda and create /dev/sdb with parted? I'll be very glad .. thanks

Comment: Gparted is a bootable tool in Linux that can grant you access to your computer's disk from where you can create, delete, rename, resize disk partitions. It gives you the same features for managing your disk when installing Linux OS. Also, if you do not intend to get Gparted, you could instead go to your CentOS terminal and type parted command to use the partition management tool that came with CentOS to create /dev/sdb or to reduce size of /dev/sda so that you can get more free space which you can use to create /dev/sdb/ Hope this helps. Here is Gparted's website https://gparted.org

Comment: I don't think parted is the right tool to create device block, for that I need to use `mknod`, I'm trying to set a persistent device block not a new partition, thanks for the help btw